# InDesign: first bullet of bullet list appears small

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, paragraph-styles, paragraph, lists

I have created a text box using rectangle tool and text tool. There in that I'm going create a bullet list. What I do is add my text in text control and select bullet list. It creates the bullet list fine. But the first bullet in the bulet list in the bullet list appears slightly small t the other bullets in the bullet list. Can anyone help me to correct this and make the bullet bring back to the same size of other bullets.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you have a character style affecting the first bullet. To do this properly create a paragraph style for the list and apply it while removing overrides. This should clean up any 'mixed' formatting.

[image]